# Doctrine2 : Detach / Merge on ManyToMany association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been strugling with those feature ([attach/merge feature](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities)).

My need is simple, I have a `BookFilterType` which filters a collection of `Book` object.

Until now, when doing

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $book = new Book($this->getUser());
    $filters = $this->getFilters();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookFilterType(), $filters);

    ...
    return array(...);
}
```

I got an **error** : `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed` because in the filter they were others entities.

So basically, i needed to store only ID's when saving the filters criterias in the session, and then re-hydrate them using `find($id)`.

But this is ugly, and my code gets unreadable !

So i've decided to go with the `detach / merge` feature.

After storing detached entities i want to merge them again to re-inject values in the form, it seems that I need to use `cascade={"merge"}` on my Object because i get :

`Class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

**THE QUESTION (finally)**

**Where do i put the `cascade={"merge"}` : On the `joinColumns` OR `inverseJoinColumns` ? or BOTH ? ? Cause I have only `ManyToMany` associations in those filters**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyTargetedEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="target_entity_nn",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="some_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="other_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 *
 **/
private $contributors;
```

PS: i'm using `Symfony2.1` / `Doctrine master`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it on the @ORM\ManyToMany

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany